# Regular Expression Date and Time

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Hi people I have the following express validation

```
    [Required]
    [RegularExpression("{0:d/M/yyyy HH:mm:ss}" , 
    ErrorMessage = "Wrong Syntax")]
    public string Posted { get; set; }`
```

But it does not allow the following input which am showing as a example of date and time: 
12/12/2011 00:00:00 (I do not want these exact numbers the date and time should allow any numbers which is allowed logically by date and time standards)

I get the error message "Wrong Syntax" even when i input the correct code. What seems to be the problem. Any help will be really appreciated Thank You So Much

Comment: Your regular expression looks like a date/time format string, not a proper regular expression.

Comment: Why are you using a `string` and not a `DateTime` for the `Posted` property?

Answer (score 7):

It is because `RegularExpressionAttribute` expects a Regex pattern and you are providing a .NET string format pattern ([MSDN: RegularExpressionAttribute Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc679267.aspx)).

For **basic** format validation you would need to use something like:

```
[RegularExpression(@"\d{2,2}/\d{2,2}/\d{4,4} \d{2,2}:\d{2,2}:\d{2,2}")]
```

Comment: A .NET date and time format string, specifically (GUID and numbers also have format strings).

Comment: I will try your answer and report back thank you if it works will give it as a correct solution if not will inform the error

Comment: It does not work after playing around it still gives an error of unrecognized escape sequence

Comment: @user1137472 Try adding an @ right before the string, like so: `[RegularExpression(@"\d{2,2}/\d{2,2}/\d{4,4} \d{2,2}:\d{2,2}:\d{2,2}")]`. This will make the compiler accept the string even if it contains unrecognized escape sequences (like `\d`).

Comment: Can you please what the numbers like d{2,2) ect... mean fare enough it works but am not the kind of guy who obtains answers and just walks off, I would really like your explanation thank you

Comment: I can't explain all of that regular expression in a comment, but have a look at this website: http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html. That's where I started learning about regex.

Comment: Thank you but can you give me a general Idea as I thought this website is for people who need help in coding and giving them code and explaining what it does is part of the job if not I am very happy for the code you have given thanks take care and god bless

Comment: you will need to change you your answer slightly as the explanation states the first digit can only be 1 or 2 digits you code stated 2 or 2 digits as this is incorrect you cant have double digit dates all the time unless you use 01 but if you want to allow only 1 you use the following: @"\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4} \d{2,2}:\d{2,2}:\d{2,2}", Thank you for the code and website

Comment: Also with your code can add months over 12 is there a way to stop this? same with the date you can add over 31 ? and when u enter all 00/00/00 00:00:00 it crashes is there a way to stop this?

Answer (score 0):

Replace your string in your `RegularExpression` attribute with a real regular expression.  Try one of these from this library site of regex's:

http://regexlib.com/DisplayPatterns.aspx?cattabindex=4&categoryId=5&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

Try the first one.

Comment: Been on this website I did my research before i posted question I cant get them to work even though they seem logical they do not give the correct validation

Answer (score 0):

For a complete guide to client and server validation in MVC (using something like a TextBoxFor), see my answer here:
[Validate Date in MM/dd/YYYY format in mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16606121/validate-date-in-mm-dd-yyyy-format-in-mvc/28993038#28993038)